# SQL Join on bound variable

Tags: java, sql

I have a dynamically generated SQL Query being built in Java. The way it is being built is by having an array of parameters to be bound and a dynamically created String representing the query. Something like this:

```
List<String> bindVariables;
String query = "Select * from TABLE where id = ?";
```

After the query is finished being created. the variables are bound in based on their index in the array. Like this:

```
query = selectPortion + fromPortion + wherePortion;
// Bind all parameters
for (int i = 0; i < bindVariables.size(); i++) {
    queryStatement.setNString(i + 1, bindVariables.get(i));
}
```

And then the query is executed.

This works fine when we are just binding variables to the WHERE clause, as it is simply just adding the condition and the variable to the end of the array. However, the issue is when I want to JOIN on a variable after the array already has some values.

```
wherePortion += "and table1.id = ? ";
bindVariables.add("15");
wherePortion += "and table2.color = ? ";
bindVariables.add("blue");

fromPortion += "INNER JOIN table3 on table3.size = ? ";
bindVariables.add(); //Here is the issue
```

Is there a recommended way to approach this situation?

Comment: You're not going to `JOIN` on a variable condition.  Your `JOIN` criteria for `table3` to whatever table you're joining to will always be the same, so I don't see how you need to dynamically create a join based on a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was looking for a `CROSS JOIN`